SSH Key Authentication Fails for GitHub Despite Correct Configuration and Matching Fingerprint
I’m trying to use SSH to connect to GitHub, but my public key authentication keeps failing. I’ve gone through the usual steps to set up my SSH keys and configure SSH, but GitHub continues to reject my public key, and it prompts me for a password instead. Here’s a summary of my setup and the steps I’ve tried so far.
Enviroment
•   Operating System: macOS
•   SSH Client: OpenSSH 9.8p1
•   Key Type: ED25519
Steps Taken
1.  Generated SSH Key: I created an ED25519 SSH key using ssh-keygen, and I confirmed that both the private (id_ed25519) and public (id_ed25519.pub) keys are in my ~/.ssh directory.
2.  Added Key to GitHub: I copied the content of id_ed25519.pub and added it to my GitHub account under “SSH and GPG keys.”
3.  Configured ~/.ssh/config: I added a specific configuration for GitHub in my ~/.ssh/config file:

Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes

    4.  Verified the Key Fingerprint: I used `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -E sha256` and `ssh-add -l -E sha256` to check the SHA256 fingerprint of my key. The fingerprint matches what GitHub displays for my added SSH key, so I’m certain it’s the correct key.
5.  Cleared and Reloaded SSH Agent: To make sure no other keys were interfering, I cleared the SSH agent with ssh-add -D and re-added my key with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`.
6.  Tested SSH Connection: When I run ssh -T git@github.com, I get prompted for a password instead of successfully authenticating with my public key.

lutao@HonorMgicM2 ~ % ssh -vT git@github.com     
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/lutao/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/lutao/.ssh/config line 17: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/lutao/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/lutao/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.8
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/lutao/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:YHpPsFYwOQgQmrar1RY7jvivHJQOHjIzZDYZjZ4HVCs
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/lutao/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/lutao/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/lutao/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/cYOBUjk2vhJs3v6uCd9wx5yoc9qlIA81pfjHTn0iNA explicit agent
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/lutao/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/cYOBUjk2vhJs3v6uCd9wx5yoc9qlIA81pfjHTn0iNA explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
(git@github.com) Password:

And I tried my all password about github,included passphrase.
